# How to modify the default list view?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list-view, custom-list, xslt-list-view-web-part

I would like to know how to modify the standard SharePoint 2010 list view in order to increase columns width for instance.

I already read the articles talking about using SharePoint Designer to manage to do it. However, any CSS or DOM changes performed with SharePoint Designer will be lost after the next deployment. (I guess)

Thereby, I would like to have the files that handling the list view (XSLT, native list webparts or everything essential for my custom list to work properly ) inside my solution.

That way, it will prevent me to do the changes again and again everytime I want to install my solution in an other Web Application. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the list column width, you can give the html code as a formula.

```
=<div style=width:"20px">
```

Like this you can change the appearance of the list by using the html code in the formula

Hope you got an idea from this.

Comment: Element '[...]:formula' can not contain a child element '[...]:div' because the content model of the parent element is plain text. Sorry it's not working at all.

Comment: If it is a calculated field, then it will be easy to achieve this. I don't think we can do this in another field type.